# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file for class: Script7 error at line 5

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am writing groovy script to save raw soap request & response and i get this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file for class: Script7 error at line 5

Here is the Script:

```
def myOutFile = context.expand( '${#TestSuite#fileName}' )+"_PostPaid-Success_Payment_BillInqReq.xml" 
def response = context.expand( '${BillInq#Request}' ) 
def f = new File(myOutFile) 
f.write(response, "UTF-8") 
file.write(context.rawRequest,'utf-8')
```

[image: Test Suite properties]

[image: Test case]

Comment: there is no `file` object created in your script which is being used in line 5. Can you test suite properties and test case screen shot? Are you using it in `Script Assertion` of `Billing` test step?. Looks you seemed to have problem for couple of weeks and different questions.

Comment: yes after i fixed the report automatic generation now i want to log raw request and response for each soap test step with the step name and i finally used the above script but when i use reference value i get the mentioned error

Comment: Thanks for the edit. where is the script located? or step number please? By the way, not sure why there are multiple groovy scripts. Every thing can be done in step. Any way, please clarify.

Comment: script is located in SaveInquiryReq groovy step. i don't know how to do this in single step

Comment: The last line of your script `file.write()` should be `f.write()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:

- Go to Test Suite `PostPaid`
- Add a custom property say `DATA_STORE_PATH` and its value to a directory name where you like to save the requests and responses
- Go to test case `PostPaid_Success_Payment`
- Disable the Step 2 & Step 3 i.e., `SaveInquiryReq` and `SaveInquiryResponse` steps. or you may remove altoger as well if no other work is done apart from save the request & response respectively.
- Click on step1 `BillInq`, click on assertions, Choose `Script Assertion`, see here for more details [how to add script assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html)
- Have below script and click ok
- Now you run the step1, you should be able to see the request and responses saved in the above mentioned directory

```groovy
/**
 * This script logs both request and response
 */

assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"
assert context.request, "Request is empty or null"

//Save the contents to a file
 def saveToFile(file, content) {
    if (!file.parentFile.exists()) {
         file.parentFile.mkdirs()
         log.info "Directory did not exist, created"
    }
    file.write(content) 
    assert file.exists(), "${file.name} not created"
 }
 def dirToStore = context.expand('${#TestSuite#DATA_STORE_PATH}')
 def currentStepName = context.currentStep.name
 def requestFileName = "${dirToStore}/${currentStepName}_request.xml"
 def responseFileName = "${dirToStore}/${currentStepName}_response.xml"
 //Save request & response to directory
 saveToFile(new File(requestFileName), context.rawRequest)
 saveToFile(new File(responseFileName), context.response)
```

Comment: it works , thanks alot, but the request is added with references not the raw request

Comment: You are so quick to try the answer. Updated script to `rawRequest`. Consider accpepting as answer & up vote if this helps.

Comment: After a long stretch :), today you followed the instructions and got the result quick. And image helped me to answer.